# Infinite Loop with setState in useEffect and state as Dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to retrieve a comment immediately after posting it. The code below does just that, after I submit my comment, I see it in the comment section. However, the only problem is that it results in an infinite loop.

```
const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        // append data for formData....
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
                headers: headers,
            });
            setAllComments(response.data);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, [allComments]);
```

When I remove the 'allComments' state from the dependency array, it does not result in an infinite loop, but after I post the comment, I have to refresh the page in order to see the comment, which is not what I want.

```
const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        // append data for formData....
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
                headers: headers,
            });
            setAllComments(response.data);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    fetchData();
}, []); // empty dependency
```

I tried using separate useEffect hooks, but it doesn't immediately post the comment, I have to refresh the page to see it.

```
 const [allComments, setAllComments] = useState([]);
 const fetchData = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        // append data for formData....
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(url, formData, {
                headers: headers,
            });
            setAllComments(response.data);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    
}, [allComments]);
```

Please help, thanks in advance!╰(▔∀▔)╯

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook will trigger everytime a variable in the dependency array changes, so there are three cases with useEffect:

1. No dependency array is provided -> useEffect triggers anytime the state/props change in the component
2. The dependency array is empty (ex. []) -> useEffect only triggers on the first render
3. The dependency array contains allComments -> useEffect will trigger when allComments is changed

Since you are changing allComments in the third case, the useEffect is infinitely triggering.

In the form for writing the comment, you should store the content of the text field in a separate state and use an event handler for the submit button that makes the post request.

Basic form:

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("")

---your fetchData function---

return(
  <input type="text" onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} value={input}/>
  <button onClick={fetchData}>Submit</button>
  ---comments list populated w/ allComments---
)
```

Here's [another in-depth example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-input-forms-with-usestate-hook-in-react/)

The above examples will then only update allComments when you've submitted a comment.